# Reliable CSS declaration expansion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, parsing

I've parsed a CSS stylesheet into an object. I'm creating an angular ui for editing the CSS properties. I need to expand shorthand properties reliably. Presently, I'm following this algorithm:

```
If the property is expandable:
    1. Get a hidden DIV.
    2. Apply the property to the DIV.
    3. Iterate through each of the properties component parts, 
        gathering a list of new properties.
    4. Replace the property with the new properties.
```

Thus,

border: 0px solid black;

becomes

```
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-top-color: black;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-right-color: black;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-bottom-color: black;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-left-color: black;
```

The problem comes with a property like:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f2f5fa 0%,#e7ebf3 100%,#7db9e8 100%);
```

On the most recent version of Chrome, it becomes:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(242, 245, 250) 0%, rgb(231, 235, 243) 100%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position: ;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-color: initial;
```

IE 10 is pretty much the same with regard to background-image, but IE9 does:

```
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-size: auto;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-clip: border-box;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-color: rgb(242, 245, 250);
```

In any case, this seems to be a very unreliable method of expanding CSS properties. Does anyone know of another that would work in the browser? Like I said earlier, I already have the CSS parsed.

**Edit (Description of purpose):**
We provide a product that, among many other things, allows the user to embed an advanced form-document editor into their site. The look of the editor can be modified by changing a .CSS file that lives on their server. My project allows people to parse in existing CSS documents, or start fresh, and edit it, with dynamic visual updates occurring to a preview of the editor. I parse the CSS into a javascript object client-side, (recently moving over to a client-side version of reworkscss that I condensed. - [Use node rework css in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769087/use-node-rework-css-in-browser)) There is a panel of css controls that bind to different properties on the model. For example, I might want to edit the font-size property in DIV.menu. However, DIV.menu might only have the property

```
font:italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
```

Because of this, we expand all shorthand properties so that all the component parts are accessible to the controls. How to do this reliably is the tricky part.

Comment: Why do you want to get the expanded values of shorthand CSS rules?

Comment: `I'm creating an angular ui for editing the CSS properties.` (Individually)

Comment: Yes, but *why*? You can edit CSS properties in the browser using the `F12` developer options.

Comment: It's part of our product - the appearance editor for the site.

Comment: I'll add a more detailed description of what I'm trying to accomplish.